# How launch pfctl without daemon?

Tags: macos

I want to run pfctl on startup since daemon not working(i dont know why).
Tell me pls how to do it correctly. I tried:

pfctl_autoload.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo pfctl -e -f /etc/pf.conf
```

/Users/username/Library/LaunchAgents/com.test.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.test.plist/string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>open</string>
        <string>-a</string>
        <string>Terminal</string>
    <string>/Users/username/Desktop/pfctl_autoload.sh</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Testing in terminal

```
launchctl load /Users/username/Library/LaunchAgents/com.test.plist
/Users/username/Library/LaunchAgents/com.test.plist: Invalid property list
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, `deamon not working` isn't a good description. What did you mean?

Comment: Hi, in  */LaunchDaemons/com.apple.pfctl.plist i added flag -e with "csrutil disable" it did not work and now i search other ways. run in manual mode - works(sudo pfctl -e -f /etc/pf.conf)

Answer (score 0):

From the terminal you could do:

```
sudo pfctl -Fa -f /tmp/your.pf.conf -e
```

To load the default rules:

```
sudo pfctl -Fa -f /etc/pf.conf
```

Or probably easier is just to enable the firewall:

Use these steps to enable the application firewall:

1. Choose System Preferences from the Apple menu.
2. Click Security or Security & Privacy.
3. Click the Firewall tab.
4. Unlock the pane by clicking the lock in the lower-left corner and
   enter the administrator username and password.
5. Click "Turn On Firewall" or "Start" to enable the firewall.
6. Click Advanced to customize the firewall configuration.

[image]

Just in case you check the rules used by killswitch at https://github.com/vpn-kill-switch/killswitch